# Form Information to Appear On Another Page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, forms

I am trying to create a form that, once submitted, will be sent to my `index.html` page for other users to view. I want it so multiple users anywhere in the world can submit information and so the website displays all their information at once.

Here is my submit page's PHP code:

```
<form action="submit_a_message.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="message" cols="60" rows="10" maxlength="500"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I am trying to figure out how to make the information submited via that form appear on my `index.html` page. This is the code I found online, but it doesn't work.  Why?

```
<?php>
    string file_get_contents ( string $submit_a_message.php [, bool $use_include_path = false [,       resource $context [, int $offset = -1 [, int $maxlen ]]]] )
<?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To make submitted text avaliable on your index page, you need a place where you would store it. You can use MySQL base to do that, or (if you can't or you really don't want) you can use text file with your texts/posts (that is not really good way, i warned you).

To do that with MySQL you can use a code like this on your `submit_a_message.php`:

```
<?php
//connection to database and stuff
...
if $_POST['message'] {
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $sql = "insert into `mytable` values $message"; //that is SQL request that inserts message into database
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); // run that SQL or show an error
}
?>
```

In order to show desired vaues from table use above-like idea, your SQL request would be like `select * from mytable where id = 123`

Answer (score 0):

if your not married to the idea of using php and learning how to manage and access a database you could use jquery and a trird party backend like parse.com

If your new to storing and retrieving data, I would definately reccomend the services that https://parse.com/ offeres. It makes storing and retrieving data trivial. Best of all, the service is free unless your app makes more than 30 API requests per second. I have an app that 61 users use daily and we have never come close to the 30 req per second limit.

To save your info, you could write:

```
$('document').ready(function(){

    $('#submit_btn').on('click',function(){ // detect button click, need to add "submit_btn" as the id for your button

        var Message = Parse.Object.extend("Message"); //create a reference to your class
        var newObject = new EventInfo(); //create a new instance of your class

        newObject.set("messageText", $("#myMessage").val()); //set some properties on the object, your input will need the id "myMessage"
        newObject.save(null, { //save the new object
          success: function(returnedObject) {
            console.log('New object created with objectId: ' + returnedObject.id); 
          },
          error: function(returnedObject, error) {
            console.log('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
          }
        });
     });
});
```

Retrieving that info later would be as easy as:

```
    var Message = Parse.Object.extend("Message"); //create a reference to your class
    var query = new Parse.Query(Message); //create a query to get stored objects with this class
    query.find({
      success: function(results) { //"results" is an array, you can fine tune your queries to retrieve specific saved objects too
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
          var object = results[i];

          $(body).append("Message #" + (i+1) + object.get("messageText"); 
        }
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log("Failed to complete Query - Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
```